# For loop to batch plot multiple files in R

Tags: r, loops

I have 5 tab files called "1.txt", "2.txt", ..., "5.txt". Each files contain one column called "x" and another one called "y".

I would like to apply a loop to generate a plot from each files individually and redirect the plots into corresponding output pdf files called respectively "1.pdf", "2.pdf", ... "5.pdf".

Here is what I tried, but I have a problem with the PDF part I guess:

```
files<-list.files(pattern=".txt")
for (input in files){
   output<-basename(file.path(input,fsep=".txt"))     # input files are in working directory
   graph<-read.table(input,header=T)
   pdf('output.pdf')
   plot(graph$x,graph$y)
   dev.off()
}
```

It produces only the first plot called "output.pdf".

How can I mention the variable "output" in the pdf function?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I am not sure if you suggested paste because my files are named "1", "2", "3", "4", "5". I mentioned these names as examples. My point was to name the output files with the same prefix as the respective input files.

Comment: My suggestion had nothing to do with the particular names of your particular files. It just happens to be the tool one would use to solve this problem.

Comment: Let's think about this: `output` contains the portion of the input file name you wish to reuse. We must pass a character value to `pdf()` to name the file. `paste` allows us to combine several strings into one string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What joran is saying in increasing pedagogical terms is that your current function overwrite your `output.pdf` five times. I wants you to be able to catch your own fish. You *must pass* something to `pdf()` to make five unique files. Something like this might help,

```
files <- list.files(pattern=".txt")
for (input in files){
   output <- basename(file.path(input,fsep=".txt")) 
   graph  <- read.table(input,header=T)
   pdf(paste0("output for ", input,".pdf"))
   plot(graph$x,graph$y)
   dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Almost there. I tried heaps of combinations. The best is when I replaced by `pdf(paste0(output,".pdf"))` it generates the files but the ".txt" extension is still there ("1.txt.pdf"). I tried to modify the `file.path` function but nothing changes. It also returns `Error in read.table(input, header = T) : more columns than column names`. Also tried with `paste` instead of `paste0` but same results. Charts are correct though !

Comment: To get rid of the `.txt` use: `output_notxt = sub(".txt", "", output)`, which essentially replaces `.txt` by an empty string.

Comment: @lqdo2000 `basename` works fine. It "removes all of the path up to and including the last path separator (if any)". It's documentation doesn't say anything about removing file extensions.

Comment: @lqdo2000, I agree with joran, you need to read the documentation.